# Quickly Plotting Polar Radar Data using Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I've got an interesting application that requires transforming 3D polar data (angle, distance, and value at that point) into images representing the data. It's NOAA NEXRAD radar data that I'm using in a custom application.

The data is stored in 3 arrays, range_data (the distance from the radar in meters, 1800 points), azimuth_data (the angle in 0.5 degree steps, 720 points), and radar_data (a 720x1800 array containing a data value for each combination of range and azimuth). This is the format I get the data in from NOAA so there's not much I can do to change things on that front.

Right now, I'm plotting it using a matplotlib pcolormesh in the following way (basically [this example from the library I'm using](https://unidata.github.io/siphon/latest/examples/Radar_Server_Level_3.html#sphx-glr-examples-radar-server-level-3-py)):

```
x = range_data * np.sin(np.deg2rad(azimuth_data))[:,None]
y = range_data * np.cos(np.deg2rad(azimuth_data))[:,None]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(4,4))
ax.pcolormesh(x,y,radar_data,cmap=ref_cmap,norm=ref_norm)
ax.set_aspect('equal','datalim')
ax.set_xlim(-460, 460)
ax.set_ylim(-460, 460)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig(imgpath, bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True, dpi=dpiCalc)
```

The major hangup right now is in the actual rendering and saving of the plot using the savefig() command. It takes around 7 seconds per image and with 20 or so sets of data to process it takes far too long for the application I have in mind.

Since I just need the colormapped data as an image, I don't really need the majority of matplotlib's tools and features. I'm thinking there must be a quicker way to generate this image from my raw data.

I tried stepping through the data and populating an x-y array piece-by-piece, then saving the array with PIL, but iterating through the data manually took way longer than even matplotlib. Doing array operations with numpy would be way faster but I can't really think of any operations to convert the data between coordinate systems.

To breakdown the question even simpler, I've got polar data stored in a 720x1800 radar_data array in the format value[angle,distance], and I want to generate a [colormapped radar image like this one](https://unidata.github.io/siphon/latest/_images/sphx_glr_Radar_Server_Level_3_001.png) (without the axes or frame) in the quickest way possible. Since I'm not a programmer nor a mathematician by trade, there might be something simple I'm overlooking.

Any and all recommendations are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you essentially want to do a polar distortion, converting this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

I did that using **ImageMagick** in the Terminal as it is easy and quick and installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. The command I used is:

```
magick image.png -virtual-pixel Black -distort Polar 0 result.png
```

**Note**: If you are using **ImageMagick** v6, replace `magick` with `convert` in the preceding command.

**Note**: In case you want to experiment, I made the initial image like this:

```
magick -size 1800x720  gradient:red-blue image.png
```

If that is what you want, you can do it in Python using any one of a number of tools:

- **skimage** - warp_polar()
- **OpenCV** - warpPolar()
- **wand** - [distort()](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.distort)

Or you could just *"shell out"* to the **ImageMagick** command I used above.

**Keywords**: Python, image processing, polar, depolar, cartesian, transform, radar, plot

Comment: I really like this answer. I saw the mapping you showed above, cartesian to polar, in a few examples during my searching but for whatever reason it didn't click exactly what was going on. The only thing I'm still struggling with is the details of the image conversion. Right now I'm generating a great looking cartesian plot in milliseconds but I'm trying to figure out how to move that image from PIL to skimage for the conversion.

Comment: Skimage works with Numpy arrays, so you can make an skimage from a PIL Image with `skimage = np.array(PILImage)` You may want to make it float and divide by 255.

Comment: My problem was actually just not realizing that warp_polar could operate on a 3D array only if you tell it to specifically accept 3D arrays. Now I’m just fighting with the origin and radius parameters to get a usable image from warp_polar because it’s not behaving right now.

Comment: You can always ask a new question and use my sample images if you have some code you want a hand with.

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib is not a good solution for that.

- [Vispy](http://vispy.org/)

  OpenGL-supported plotting. Interface is not that polished, but a lot of functions are already available. Just click through the [examples](https://github.com/vispy/vispy/tree/master/examples) and try to find the functions where you don't have to write GLSL (the ones not in folder "gloo" but in "plot" or "scene").
- [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)

  Works fine for realtime plotting, but is currently unmaintained. Qt4 only.
- [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/)

  Also unmaintained. Qt4 only.

You can also put together a custom GUI without that much work, there are many examples around. e.g. [here](https://www.swharden.com/wp/2013-05-08-realtime-data-plotting-in-python/). Just look for "real time plotting Qt".

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that the following code takes 1 second for me:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

t = time.time()
range_data = np.arange(1800)
azimuth_data = np.linspace(0, 359.5, 720)
radar_data = np.dot(np.atleast_2d(azimuth_data).T , np.atleast_2d(range_data))

x = range_data * np.sin(np.deg2rad(azimuth_data))[:,None]
y = range_data * np.cos(np.deg2rad(azimuth_data))[:,None]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(4,4))
ax.pcolormesh(x,y,radar_data)
ax.set_aspect('equal','datalim')

ax.set_axis_off()

plt.savefig("radar.png", transparent=True, dpi=100)
print(time.time()-t)
```

If you half the resolution, i.e. 900 x 360 points instead of 1800 x 720, it would only take 0.3 seconds. So it's also mainly a question of how large of an image you want to get.

Comment: It's probably a matter of processing power. The DPI I'm using is 900 so that's definitely one of the reasons it takes far longer than your example. Sadly the application I'm developing for is going to be run on lower-power laptops and mobile devices which means there's not much more matplotlib can do for me. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The standard screen resolution of a laptop is maximum 1020p. This means that (a) figure size times dpi should not be more than 1000. (b) the range resolution should not be more than 1020/2. Everything above will be wasted. Plugging that in will result in 0.35 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are already doing this, just to be sure:
If your `azimuth_data` is not a numpy array, you could lose performance.