# Alternatives for real-time line plotting other than maplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly, blender

I am currently extracting **positional data from G-Code** of a model and using it to simulate a real-time line plot, layer by layer. So far I have tested **matplotlib** and **plotly**. The simulation works fine but after each line plot it starts to slow down to a point where you are not able to interact with the plot anymore.

**I need fast alternatives to simulate my problem which allows me to interact with the plot in real-time as well as after the plotting is complete.**

[Example Plotting in Plotly Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXYiG.gif)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207651/7919597

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly Plotting Polar Radar Data using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206372/quickly-plotting-polar-radar-data-using-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470518/how-to-increase-speed-and-split-data-with-multiple-plots-using-pyqtgraph/59472193#59472193

Comment: As it stands, your question is very near to be closed because it essentially asks for software recommendations. If you can produce a short example of what you're doing and include the code in your question, it is possible that someone will point you to some non-obvious time traps or possible optimizations.